# grep a time hh:mm:ss

Tags: linux, bash, grep

i need to split a given date format (hh:mm:ss) like: 10:30:50
in varibles like: hour=10; minute=30 and seconds=50 whit grep in a bash script.

I get the time un a variable, for example: time="10:30:50"
And I only get the seconds with the follow expression:

> seconds=`echo $time | grep -oE "[^:]+$"`

Any help to get the minutes and hours?

Answer (score 8):

Use `read`. It is a shell built-in command so is more efficient than `grep`, `sed` and other external commands.

```
time="10:30:50"
IFS=: read hr min sec <<< "$time"
```

Output:

```
$ echo "$hr"
10
$ echo "$min"
30
$  echo "$sec"
50
```

Answer (score 1):

see below :

```
kent$  time="10:30:50"

kent$  h=$(awk -F: '$0=$1' <<<"$time")
kent$  m=$(awk -F: '$0=$2' <<<"$time")                                                                                                                                      
kent$  s=$(awk -F: '$0=$3' <<<"$time")                                                                                                                                      

kent$  echo $h,$m,$s
10,30,50
```

Comment: are you sure you cp the right command? anyway dogbane's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
echo '10:30:50' | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\)/hours=\1 minutes=\2 seconds=\3/'
```

Make it a function:

```
function stringToTime() {
    eval $( echo "$1" | sed 's/\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+\)/hours=\1 minutes=\2 seconds=\3/' )
}
```

Now you can call it:

```
stringToTime 10:30:50
echo $hours hours, $minutes minutes and $seconds seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

sed, grep, awk are external commands , try to use shell  builtin command to extract your needed information

```
D=12:10:12

IFS=:

read H M S <<< $D
```

NOTE: <<< means read from a variable

Answer (score 0):

@fedorqui,
@kent,

```
$ echo ${time:0:2}
10

$ echo ${time:3:2}
30

$ echo ${time:6:2}
50
```